# How to get drop event in Eclipse RCP tableview cell

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am new to eclipse rcp and i was creating a table and a tree for drag and drop.
Tree will have list of nodes which can be drag and drop in table particular cell.

Drag and Drop does work fine but i am not able to drop the node text in particular cell of a table. Always it update the first column of the table.

Please if anyone have any idea of this.

Comment: Are you using `ViewerDropAdapter`?

Comment: no, i am not using ViewerDropAdapter.

Comment: Please help me if anyone knows the answer. i am really in a trouble..